# Where can I find System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server dll?

Tags: c#, reference, assemblies, system.web

Where can I find System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server dll.
I want to use Server.MapPath() in my code and it requires System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server namespace.
Even from references I couldn't find and add System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server to my solution.
Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right Click **References** >> then click **Add Reference** and Under **Assemblies** click **Framework** and Search **System.Web** and check the **checkbox** and click **OK** button to add it's reference in your project:

[image]

You have reference of `System.Web` now and Now you can use all Types and methods which are under `System.Web` namespace/assembly it, in your case `HttpContext`:

`System.Web.HttpContext`

Answer (score 5):

`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server` isn't a namespace. Let's break it down:

- [`System.Web`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web) is a namespace
- [`HttpContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext) is a type (in the `System.Web` assembly)
- [`Current`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current) is a static property within `HttpContext`, returning an `HttpContext` reference
- [`Server`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.server) is an instance property within `HttpContext`, of type `HttpServerUtility`

So the *assembly* you need is `System.Web`; the *namespace* you need in a `using` directive (if you want one) is `System.Web`.

So:

```
using System.Web;
...
var path = HttpContext.Server.Current.MapPath(...);
```

Note that a more modern equivalent is [`HostingEnvironment.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which doesn't rely on a current HTTP context, as far as I'm aware. (`HostingEnvironment` is in the `System.Web.Hosting` namespace, but still in the `System.Web` assembly.)

Answer (score 2):

it's a sub of `System.Web`. you should add reference to `System.Web`.